How to get the last characters in a string arithmetically?
I have a hex string I want to print out 32 characters at a time, starting from the right and going left. E.g.
11010401c3cf0e0e383434d0c0c302c2cb0a0a28242490808201c1c7060618141450404100c0c302020804041
should print as
60618141450404100c0c302020804041
0c302c2cb0a0a28242490808201c1c70
000000011010401c3cf0e0e383434d0c

I tried:
for i in range(len(hex_str)//32+1):
    print(hex_str[-32*(i+1):-32*i].zfill(32))

but this gives the incorrect output:
00000000000000000000000000000000
0c302c2cb0a0a28242490808201c1c70
000000011010401c3cf0e0e383434d0c

This is because in the first iteration, -32*i evaluates to 0 and so the slicing is hex_str[-32:0] which returns None. I know the proper syntax is hex_str[-32:], but how do I get that in a loop like this? My best solution is
for i in range(len(inject)//32+1):
    print(hex_str[-32*(i+1):-32*i or None].zfill(32))

Feels ugly though. Should I just be OK with that feeling, or is there something slicker I'm unaware of?

I would try using the step parameter of range.

Your code only works if the string is a multiple of 32 in length. Otherwise, you should use a range that starts at the length-32 and goes down.

Slicing never returns None. It returns an empty string.

Yes it's ugly, but it works.  The other way around it would be to use positive numbers instead of negative.

If you have Python 3.12, you can use itertools.batched:
from itertools import batched

string = "11010401c3cf0e0e383434d0c0c302c2cb0a0a28242490808201c1c7060618141450404100c0c302020804041"

batch_size = 32

for batch in batched(reversed(string), n=batch_size):
    padded = "".join(reversed(batch)).zfill(batch_size)
    print(padded)

Output:
60618141450404100c0c302020804041
0c302c2cb0a0a28242490808201c1c70
000000011010401c3cf0e0e383434d0c


Alternatively, if you don't have Python 3.12, you could do:
from itertools import zip_longest

string = "11010401c3cf0e0e383434d0c0c302c2cb0a0a28242490808201c1c7060618141450404100c0c302020804041"

batch_size = 32

iterables = [iter(reversed(string))] * batch_size

for batch in zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue="0"):
    padded = "".join(reversed(batch))
    print(padded)


Iterating over the positive stop-indices:
s = '11010401c3cf0e0e383434d0c0c302c2cb0a0a28242490808201c1c7060618141450404100c0c302020804041'

for i in range(len(s), 0, -32):
    print(s[max(i-32, 0) : i].zfill(32))

Or with negative indices like yours:
for i in range(0, -len(s), -32):
    print(s[i-32 : i or None].zfill(32))

Or if you don't have huge strings:
while s:
    print(s[-32:].zfill(32))
    s = s[:-32]

Or if you do:
b = bytearray(s, 'ascii')
while b:
    print(b[-32:].decode().zfill(32))
    del b[-32:]

Or inspired by Barmar's:
n = len(s)
while n >= 32:
    print(s[n-32:n])
    n -= 32
if n:
    print(s[:n].zfill(32))

Attempt This Online!

Pad the original string once, using the length of the string, then iterate over positive indices in reverse order.
x = '11010401c3cf0e0e383434d0c0c302c2cb0a0a28242490808201c1c7060618141450404100c0c302020804041'

new_l = len(x) // -32 * -32  # Round up to nearest multiple of 32
new_x = x.zfill(new_l)

for i in range(new_l - 32, -1, -32):
    print(new_x[i:i+32])


Or new_l = len(x) // -32 * -32.

Oh, that's nice. I've never seen that particular formulation before.

def reverseChunkPrint(s):
    padding = (32-len(s)%32)%32
    chunks = (len(s)+padding)//32
    for i in range(chunks):
        start = len(s) - (i+1)*32
        end = start + 32
        start = max(0,start)
        p = ('0'*padding) if (start == 0) else ""
        print(p,s[start:end],sep="")



reverseChunkPrint("11010401c3cf0e0e383434d0c0c302c2cb0a0a28242490808201c1c7060618141450404100c0c302020804041")

Prints out:
60618141450404100c0c302020804041
0c302c2cb0a0a28242490808201c1c70
000000011010401c3cf0e0e383434d0c


To progrmatically generate a slice "up to the end" of a sequence, you may fill the value after the : with a None:
print("1234"[-1:None]) will print 4. To generate a None if you have a 0, just use the inline if expression value if value != 0 else None, or the operator or which will take the second expression if the first one evaluates to False (the advantage being you don't have to repeat your calculated value). So, the solution you are calling "ugly"  is actually the correct one (and I personally don't find it ugly): hex_str[-32*(i+1):-32*i or None]
Another way is to create an "slice" instance and use it inside the [] insted of the expressions separated by :. This allows one to calculate the start and ending indexes in other rows if needed - but still, the "stop"  parameter for the slice has to be None (and not 0):
range_ = slice(-32 * (i + 1), - 32 * i or None)
print(hex_str[range_].zfill(32))

Also note that usually the string formatting mini-language  in f-strings will be preferred to the ancient "zfill"  method (Although it is just good, and the f-string is less readable in this case):
print(f"{hex_str[range_]:>032d}")


Loop from len(hex_str)-32 down to 0 by 32. This will print all but the first chunk.
Then you can use modulus to get the last chunk. If it's not empty (because the string is not a multiple of 32) you can padd it with zeroes.
hex_str = '11010401c3cf0e0e383434d0c0c302c2cb0a0a28242490808201c1c7060618141450404100c0c302020804041'
for i in range(len(hex_str)-32, -1, -32):
    print(hex_str[i:i+32])
first_block = hex_str[:len(hex_str) % 32]
if first_block:
    print(first_block.zfill(32))

